# Store Laravel Passport access token in a cookie

Tags: laravel, cookies, access-token, laravel-passport

Is it safe to store the access token in a cookie?

I've checked, and even if you have the access token, if you are not properly logged in, you will get a 401.

The access token is changing (I'm changing it) every time the user logs in.

The cookie gets destroyed on sign out or on timeout (based on the rememberme option).

Should I anyway store it somewhere else? Where about?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question but it could provide you with an alternative approach. Laravel Passport has built in support for [consuming an API with a Javascript application](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however, I already had that in place and it didn't work.. I manually had to store the token in a cookie and use it in the Authorization header: `Bearer + accesstoken`

Comment: did you get an answer? how did you managed this?  I want to save token in a cookie, not in localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe, but still you need to add middleware on your routes

Before we are using JWT AUth, this is our solution on frontend side on login page

```
axios({method: 'post', 
      data: {email: this.email.trim(), 
             password: this.password}, 
             url: '/api/login'})
.then(res => {

    if (res.data.success) {

      // Sets the Cookie Expiration Time to 1 Hour same as JWT Token on the Backend
      var now = new Date();
      now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);
      document.cookie = "ut=" + res.data.data.type;
      document.cookie = "api_token=" + res.data.data.token;
      document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"

      // Redirect to a new URL, or do something on success
       window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    }

}).catch(function (error) {
  //error 
});
```

Any suggestions?